# How can I set the date range of a selected month in FullCalendar React without infinite rerendering?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

Is there a way to put the date range of the month selected in a state in FullCalendar React?

What I'd like to do is put the dateRange in a state so that I can display specific elements next to my calendar, and this element will change when the user changes month.

I saw in the documentation that there was a dateSet method and I expected it to work, but it creates an infinite rerender of the component, which leads to an error.

I'm a bit of a beginner in react and FullCalendar, so it may be a silly mistake on my part, but I haven't found an answer elsewhere.

```
const [dateRange,setDateRange]=useState<any>()

<Box flex="1 1 100%" ml="15px" sx={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius:3, boxShadow: '0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)', p:3, marginBottom:2, width:'100%'}}>
<FullCalendar
  height="75vh"
  locales={[enLocale, frLocale]}
  locale={frLocale}
  weekNumberCalculation={"ISO"}
  plugins={[
    dayGridPlugin,
    timeGridPlugin,
    interactionPlugin,
    listPlugin,
  ]}
  headerToolbar={{
    left: "prev,next today",
    center: "title",
    right:rightElement,
  }}
  initialView={dayGridMonth'}
  editable={true}
  selectable={true}
  selectMirror={true}


  datesSet={(arg)=> setDateRange(arg)}


  dayMaxEvents={true}
  select={handleDateClick}
  eventChange={handleEventChange}
  eventClick={handleEventClick}
  eventsSet={(events:any) => setCurrentEvents(events)}
  initialEvents={newArray}
/>
</Box>
```

Comment: Can you share more of the code? Specifically, the implementation of `setDateRange` and the component that wraps FC?

Comment: I edit the question , the component that wraps FC is a box from MUI and I add the dateRange state